# Dirt won't turn into grass after several days

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

[image][image]I made a minecraft world a few days ago, and I noticed that the dirt blocks that I put down never grew into grass blocks. It's touching other grass blocks and it is outside in the sun. Why is the grass not growing back?

Version: 1.10.0.4 Beta Minecraft Windows 10 Edition

Comment: Just to clarify, are you in creative at all, or use commands to give yourself those dirt blocks?

Comment: If you could also post a screenshot, that would help too :)

Comment: Updating your game will help alot. Windows 10 Edition has been out of Beta for a very long time, and that could be a bug that got patched later on.

Comment: This is not creative.

Comment: Were the chunks loaded for several days, or were you just waiting in the world for several days?

Comment: I was waiting in the world for several days.

Comment: That's why, then. I will add an answer explaining.

Comment: BTW, it looks like you haven't read [the tour page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) yet. I would highly recommend reading it to make your experience on Arqade the best it can be.

Comment: Actually - can you double check that these blocks aren't [coarse dirt](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Coarse_Dirt)?

Comment: I can confirm that all the blocks are dirt.

Comment: The sheep probably ate the grass over time.

Comment: Please don't edit in things not relevant to your question.  You have an answer.  Two of them, in fact.  Please read them and see if they might meet your needs.

Comment: None of the answers helped. I know that it is not coarse grass, and I've been in the same chunk for long enough for the dirt to grow back. It's still the exact same.

Comment: Then edit your question to clarify what it is you're looking for.  Unhelpful answers are a sign of a vague question.

Comment: @Frank I just need help on how to solve this problem.

Comment: So edit your question to make it clearer what you need help with.  Doing so will bump it back to the top of the list, and perhaps you will get an answer that helps.

Comment: I suggest you report this bug on the Minecraft issue tracker

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of potential causes for this.

1. The area hasn't been loaded

- 

The requirements for grass to grow have, from your screenshots, all been met. There is enough light and grass around for the grass to spread naturally. Sometimes one or two blocks might be a bit defiant, and refuse to spread, but with the amount you have, this is unlikely. The only other thing is that the area *needs to be loaded*. [Chunk Loading](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk#Loaded_and_unloaded_chunks) means that if you are not in the area (for example, you might be in the Nether), that area is not loaded - which means all activity stops. Your crops don't grow, sheep don't regrow their wool, and the grass does not spread.

2. The dirt blocks you are using are Coarse Dirt

- 

[Coarse Dirt](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Coarse_Dirt) was added in version 1.7, and is almost identical to normal dirt blocks, save for a mildly different pattern, and the fact that grass will not grow on these blocks. *However*, if you use a hoe on these blocks, it will change it into normal dirt blocks (Added in 1.8). Grass can then grow on these blocks.

Comment: I think it's weird because I am in the same area where the dirt is but it just refuses to grow.. It is also not Coarse Dirt. Do you think it's just my world?

Comment: @JuhoMoon how quickly do the crops in the area grow?

Comment: It grows regularly as in other worlds.

Comment: @JuhoMoon if they are still not growing the grass, try using a how on them regardless. When they rest back to dirt blocks, that should "update" them, and they should grow the grass properly after that

Comment: I tried and it's still the same.

Comment: Ok, one last attempt: in the chat type `/gamerule randomTickSpeed 100` (yes, it is case sensitive). This will speed up how fast everything grows. If that still doesn't affect it, then I am at a loss, unfortunately! (When you want to reset it, the default value is 3 - `/gamerule randomTickSpeed 3`

Comment: I figured out the problem. Apparently, the coding for dirt block and coarse dirt has switched. I tested this in my world and found out the coarse dirt tuned into grass...

Comment: @JuhoMoon that is incredibly unique

Answer (score 2):

In the comments, you explained that you were not actually in your world for several days, you were waiting outside of it for several days. You have to be in your world and relatively close to the chunk for it to actually load. Other than that, it meets [all the criteria](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Grass_Block) for grass to grow (read the "growth" section).

So, your grass did not grow because you were not in your world, and the chunks with the grass blocks were not loaded. Go into your world and stay around the general area of those dirt blocks, and they will grow into grass.

Comment: I have been playing for hours.

Comment: There might be a setting that  I don't have on that I don't know?

Comment: It's still the same.

Comment: @JuhoMoon were you playing at or near the location of your grass blocks? If not, the chunks will not have loaded and the grass will not have grown.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screen shot you are playing Minecraft Beta (snapshot) 1.10.0.4, and this the newest release of Minecraft with the Village and Pillage update, however the snapshot versions can be buggy. The grass not regenerating is a confirmed bug with Mojang. None of my worlds created in this snapshot will regenerate grass, and after a few days with sheep eating grass my world looks like yours. The bug will hopefully be fixed in the next snapshot, however if you unsubscribe from the beta in your Xbox Insider account, reinstall the game, the grass will work properly. Hope this helps